# How remove pagination from woocommerce storefront theme

Tags: wordpress

How remove pagination from woocommerce storefront theme.

[image: follow this image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change number of product per page. You can overwrite it using below code. put it on function.php file of your active theme

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'new_loop_shop_per_page', 20 );

function new_loop_shop_per_page( $cols ) {
  // $cols contains the current number of products per page based on the
  //value stored on Options -> Reading
  // Return the number of products you wanna show per page.
  $cols = 90;
  return $cols;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce > Product Page > uncheck Product Pagination

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'storefront_woocommerce_pagination', 30 );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way (in `functions.php` or a plugin):

```
// Priority=11 to go after the Storefront's hook.
add_filter( 'theme_mod_storefront_product_pagination', '__return_false', 11 );
```